# How can I create a dynamic instance of a class for a text based grid?

Tags: python, class, instance, text-based

I'm trying to make a 10x10 grid for a map for a basic text-based game in python.
I managed to create a `MapTile` class and a player class that can move about an `(x, y)` grid.  I'm not sure however, how to create the instances of the class to have individual MapTiles.  I've read that it would be arbitrary to create maptile1, maptile2... etc. for all 100 `MapTile`s, but I can't think of another way..

Here's what I've got!

```
# This class contains the x and y values for a grid
class MapTile:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

# basic char class containing position
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # movement func
    def Move(self, Direction):
        if Direction.upper() == "UP":
            if self.y > 1:
                self.y -= 1
        elif Direction.upper() == "LEFT":
            if self.x > 1:
                self.x -= 1
        elif Direction.upper() == "RIGHT":
            if self.x < 10:
                self.x += 1
        elif Direction.upper() == "DOWN":
            if self.y < 10:
                self.y += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n========\nHP = {}\nX = {}\nY = {}".format(self.name,
                                                              self.hp,
                                                              self.x,
                                                              self.y)
```

Let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: Put the 10x10 grid of `MapTile` instances in a `list`-of-`lists` that is indexed by `[x][y]`or a dictionary whose keys are `tuple`s of the `(x, y)` position of each.

Comment: So I should only have one instance and the (x,y) coordinates should be a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I think you should use either a list-of-lists or a dictionary as a container for all the `MapTile` instances. Here's how to do both of them:

```
# This class contains the x and y values for a grid
class MapTile:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

XDIM, YDIM = 10, 10

# Create a list-of-lists.
grid = [[MapTile(x, y) for y in range(YDIM)] for x in range(XDIM)]

# Create a dictionary with tuple keys.
grid = {(x, y): MapTile(x, y) for x in range(XDIM) for y in range(YDIM)}
```

Doing something like this makes the x, y position information stored in the `MapTile` instances somewhat redundant, since it will be *implied* either by the indices or the keys used to reference each instance in the container.
For example:

`grid[1][2]` contains `MapTile(1, 2)`

in the first case, or

`grid[(1, 2)]` contains `MapTile(1, 2)`

in the second scenario. For that reason, you may want to leave it out of the `MapTile` class in your design. Otherwise, you're likely going to need update them when the location of their `MapTile` instance is changed within whatever type of `grid` container you've chosen to use.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Matt: Another suggestion would be to consider creating yet another class, such as `class Game`, or `Board`, or something like that, which _has_ a `grid()` attribute, controls its creation, and provides other methods to manipulate the collection of `MapTile` instances it contains (like moving or drawing them). This class could also contain the instance(s) of the character(s) if that makes sense.

Comment: I like that idea! How would I go about drawing the instances?

Comment: This is getting too far off-topic to continue much further, however that could be done by adding a `draw()` method to the `MapTile` class that accepts `x` and `y` arguments, so the class doesn't need to remember them. The `draw()` method of the `Board` class can iterate through the ones in its `grid` attribute and tell each one when to draw itself (and where to do so). It's called OOP (object-oriented programming).